# Why is this callback value blank in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a simple page. When I submit the form; I want to return the result that I get on the PHP page on the HTML page.

I have done the following:

```
     <form id="myForm" action="addfaq.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input class="form-control focus" type="text" placeholder="Enter FAQ"  name="faqQuestion" id = "faqQuestion">
     <textarea class="form-control focus" placeholder="Enter FAQ description" name="faqDesc" id="faqDesc" draggable="false" style="resize:none" rows="4" cols="48"></textarea>
      Select Images : <input type="file" id="files" name="img[]" accept="image/jpeg" multiple />
      <button class="btn btn-info" id = "submit" name="submit_button">Submit</button>
```

This is my javascript code :

```
$("#submit").click( function() {

if( $("#faqQuestion").val() == "" || $("#faqDesc").val() == "" ){
    $("#message").html("Question / description are mandatory fields -- Please Enter.");
} else{

    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
         function(info) {
            $("#message").empty();
            $("#message").html("log = " + info);
            console.log("log = " + info);
            clear();
         });

    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
    return false;
    });
}
});
function clear() {

   $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
      $(this).val("");
   }); 
}
```

The PHP code is for taking the form inputs from the user The PHP code is for taking the form inputs from the userThe PHP code is for taking the form inputs from the userThe PHP code is for taking the form inputs from the user:

```
   <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit_button']))
   {
    $faqQuestion = $_POST['faqQuestion'];
    $faqDesc=$_POST['faqDesc'];
    $faqRole=$_POST['faqRole'];

    if ($faqQuestion=="" and $faqDesc="" and $faqRole="")
    {
        echo "Incomplete information";
    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($_FILES['img'])){

                // Database connectivity and query to database

                $retval = mysql_query($sql);
                if($retval){
                    echo "Question uploaded";
                } else{
                    echo "Problem uploading question";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Duplicate question";
            }
            mysql_close($con);
        }
     }
    }
    ?>
```

The PHP code for inserting the info of above form to the database. The problem is that; the callback that my javascript gets is blank. Hence I am unable to get the result on the HTML page. Please correct me.

Comment: show us the return from php

Comment: need to see `addfaq.php`

Comment: @dandavis  I have added the PHP code.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have added PHP code

Comment: You should really, really not be using mysql_query anymore. Ditch whatever learning materials you are using because you are using a function library that has been deprecated for security issues, and is being removed in PHP7. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @Fiskie Thanks for the suggestion. I will keep that in my mind.

Comment: The first condition returns the message "Question / description are mandatory fields -- Please Enter." correctly. The problem is in else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only add this line in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit_button">
```

This will solve your issue.

And also do not forget to add `faqRole` field in your form.

Comment: It runs just fine when I run the php script normally. However, when I use it with ajax, it doesnt work. The console shows the redirection from html to php script. And nothing gets returned from the php script.

Comment: Your button `#submit` is in the form so remove `$("#myForm").submit( function() {
    return false;
    });` and add only return false at the end.

Comment: lon Navigated to http://localhost/FAQ/index.html
jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/FAQ/addfaq.php".send @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4m.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4m.(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ my_script.js:7jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4670elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4338
my_script.js:12 log =

Comment: lon I removed the $("#myForm").submit( function() { return false; }); and add only return false at the end. It didnt work.

Comment: @Nevermore keep your code as it was and check my updated answer. add only those two fields in your form.

Comment: lon I have faqRole as a name attribute in the dropdown.

Comment: @Nevermore ok, just only add the `<input type="hidden" name="submit_button">`

Comment: lon I added <input type="hidden" name="submit_button"> it still doesnt show anything in the callback

Comment: @Nevermore Check your console log.

Comment: lon I think I have something messed up in my PHP. I am debuggin it. Console log shows blank output. It is supposed to show the message ie. info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92634/discussion-between-neel-ion-and-nevermore).

Comment: @Nevermore come on chat it is working fine in my localhost. All codes are same.